# How to access a matrix to a m file from another m file?

Tags: matlab

Suppose the matrix is A which is in a m file new1.m . Now I want to access this matrix to another m file new2.m . How can it be done ?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing some code really. Have you tried saving the matrix as a `.mat` file and `load` it in the other `m` file? http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/save.html

Comment: Use `run('new1.m')` inside the file `new2.m`?

Comment: @ David, thank you for reply, but I dont want to create a mat file, just to create a matrix in new1.m such that the matrix can be further accessed in new2.m .

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little nonspecific, but I'll try to answer.
There are several ways to do this,

Assuming that you have a m-file (script) named '*new1*' with (for example) `A = rand(4)` in it. You could just run it in *new2.m* before you want to use A

```
new1;
B = 2*A;
```

Note that *new1* will return **all** the other variables assigned in it, flooding your workspace. Perhaps not a problem, but if so, you could just clear them with
`clear var1 var2 var2` etc.

Another way is to make *new1* into a function and return (only) A

```
function A = new1()
```

but I'm guessing that might ruin some other purposes of new1.
In that case you could return A only if the function is called with a special input argument (for example '*getA*')

```
function new1(varargin)
...
... % some code
...
if nargin && strcmp(varargin{1},'getA')
   assignin('caller','A',A);
end
```

And so from *new2*, just call the function.

```
new1('getA');
```